# TextField returning Nil

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uitextfield

I have custom `UITextField` in the `UICollectionView`, the `textfield` returns null always even if I pass some value from it , and the app crashes on the button click

Code:

```
func accountCollectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView?, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath?) -> UICollectionViewCell?
  {
  let cell : RBLoginCell = collectionView!.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "RBLoginCell", for: indexPath!) as! RBLoginCell


    cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear

    switch indexPath!.row {
    case 0:
        let txtFldUserId = cell.txtFld
        txtFldUserId?.delegate = self
         txtFldUserId?.placeholder = "Email Address"
         txtFldUserId?.tag = 1
         txtFldUserId?.keyboardType = .emailAddress
         txtFldUserId?.returnKeyType = .next
         txtFldUserId?.isSecureTextEntry = false

        break
    case 1:
        let  txtFldPassword = cell.txtFld
         txtFldPassword?.delegate = self
         txtFldPassword?.placeholder = "Password"
         txtFldPassword?.tag = 2
         txtFldPassword?.returnKeyType = .done
         txtFldPassword?.isSecureTextEntry = true

        break
    default:
        break
    }
    cell.setNeedsLayout()
    return cell
}
```

on this method the app crashes while checking for the charcter count

> 

```
    func loginAction(sender:UIButton!)
   {

    if (txtFldUserId?.text?.characters.count)! > 0 {
        if (txtFldPassword?.text?.characters.count)! > 0 {
            user?.emailAddress =  txtFldUserId?.text
            user?.password =  txtFldPassword?.text
            postLoginRequest(user)
```

> Custom cell class

```
class RBLoginCell  : RBParentCell {
    var txtFld : CustomTextField?
    var separator : UIView?


    override init(frame: CGRect) {
    super.init(frame: frame)
    txtFld = getTextField()
    separator = getImageView()


    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

    override func getLabel() -> UILabel? {
        let _lblInfo = UILabel(frame: CGRect.zero)
        _lblInfo.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
        _lblInfo.textAlignment = .left
        _lblInfo.textColor = UIColor.white
        _lblInfo.numberOfLines = 0
        addSubview(_lblInfo)
        return _lblInfo
    }

    func getTextField(_ frame: CGRect) -> CustomTextField? {
        let textField = CustomTextField(frame: frame)
        textField.borderStyle = .none
        textField.placeholder = ""
        textField.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
        textField.autocorrectionType = .no
        // no auto correction support
        textField.keyboardType = .default
        // use the default type input method (entire keyboard)
        textField.returnKeyType = .next
        textField.enablesReturnKeyAutomatically = false
        textField.clearButtonMode = .never
        textField.text = ""
        textField.contentVerticalAlignment = .center
        textField.autocapitalizationType = .none
        //textField.frame                     = CGRectMake(X, Y,Width,Height);
        textField.alpha = 1.0
        textField.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
        let lblleft: UILabel? = getLabel()
        lblleft?.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 20, width: self.frame.size.width, height: self.frame.size.height)
        lblleft?.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
        lblleft?.text = "\n+91"
        lblleft?.font = UIFont(name: Constants.HelveticaNeue, size: 14)//FONT_HelveticaNeue(14.0)
        lblleft?.textColor = UIColor(hexString: "555555")
        textField.leftView = lblleft
        textField.leftViewMode = .never

        addSubview(textField)
        return textField
    }

    override func getImageView() -> UIImageView? {
        let imageView = UIImageView(frame: CGRect.zero)
        imageView.backgroundColor = UIColor.lightGray
        addSubview(imageView)
        return imageView
    }

    override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()
        txtFld?.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: self.frame.size.width, height: self.frame.size.height-1)

        separator?.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: (txtFld?.frame.size.height)!, width: frame.size.width, height: 1)
    }
```

Comment: are you using storyboards to define cell type?

Comment: no i am creating by code

Comment: explain your problem more clearly. Right now you show `cellForRowAt` implementation, but you claim that the problem is in custom textField (where is the textField Implementation?), then you mention passing value from it (what and where?), and finally you claim an app crash on button click (what is the line of code that crashes? which button?)

Comment: I am passing the value in the text field from simulator, so when i click the login button the value comes nil, because i am checking for the character count

Comment: dont explain with 1 sentence in the comments. there is an edit button on the question, press it, and provide ALL the relevant information and ALL the relevant source code

Comment: Provide source code of RBLoginCell

Comment: i added the code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have initialised

```
let txtFldUserId = cell.txtFld
```

and

```
let txtFldPassword = cell.txtFld
```

in your `cellForItemAt` method, how can you access it in loginAction method then?

If you have initialised `txtFldUserId` and `txtFldPassword` in your view controller, then remove `let` from the `cellForItemAt` method like

```
txtFldUserId = cell.txtFld
txtFldPassword = cell.txtFld
```

[I am assuming you have initialised in your viewController

```
var txtFldUserId: UITextField?
var txtFldPassword: UITextField?
```

because you are not getting compiler error in your loginAction method ]